# Facebook Open Graph doesn't catch meta tag

Tags: facebook

I'm facing with an extremely weird issue regarding to Facebook Open Graph.

=> The issue is showing in the following url: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Ffancydistrict.com%2Fvideo%2Fvietnam-for-fall-break

You can see that there are 2 errors: 
"The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags." 
"The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:title, og:image, og:description"

However, if you check the header of the page: https://fancydistrict.com/video/vietnam-for-fall-break

You can see

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="FDMag">
<meta property="og:title" content="Vietnam for fall break! | FD Mag">
<meta property="og:description" content="GUYS I'M IN VIETNAM! I'm here for fall break with my parents and I'm so excited to share this adventure!">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://fancydistrict.com/video/vietnam-for-fall-break">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://fancydistrict.com/upload/media/posts/2017-10/14/77a55855ebe746c6a8a04e1de932eabb_1508008518-b.jpg" />
```

The og meta tag is there. If I scrape my URL again on Facebook sharing debugger tool, It will be fixed ... I have to manually scrape every post of my page due to the issue.

My question is that, does the error happen because of some types of caching or what? and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I’m having the same issue